# MFP 6.3.0 – AppCenter does not work after fix pack installation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter, mobilefirst-appcenter

We installed the MFP 6.3.0.0-MFPF-IF201508202339 fix using Installation Manager without errors.  After this, we also replace the administration services WAR file using Server Configuration Tool.

The operations console and apps are working fine, but the AppCenter console does not work.

When the user is trying to execute any action (change app description, permissions, etc) the app executes a logout process, sending this message “Your session has expired. You will be redirected to the authentication page.”

During the update using IM, we had no choice to change “Install Application Center” because the screens related to the last fix installation step were disabled, so the war files related to the appcenter were updated in the apps folders related to our Liberty profile instance.

In the message.log files no errors appears, just this line:

"[9/1/15 15:26:35:090 ART] 000000a7 com.ibm.appcenter.servlet.ConsoleServicesServlet             W logout"

Need I execute another additional process for the AppCenter update?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no additional process for an AppCenter update is needed.

But something got messed up here. I do not have a complete answer, but maybe some technical insight helps:

The immediate logout symptom indicates a loss of the LTPA token. This token remembers who is logged in. First, you should verify the role mapping of appcenteradmin and appcenteruser in your webserver. Secondly, the immediate logout and loss of LTPA token can be caused by any HTTP response "403 FORBIDDEN", so for instance if you have IHS or a firewall, you should check their configurations whether they interject the response "403 FORBIDDEN".

If these technical hints do not help, I suggest that you contact official IBM support, because without understanding the details of your topology and without the log files, it is difficult to analyze the problem.

Comment: Thanks Georg for your response.
Based on your input,  I checked this on the same VM where AppCenter is installed using localhost having the same behavior. Roles were already verified.
I’m going to open a PMR for IBM Support. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. From the WebSphere console, expand 'Applications' and click on 
   'WebSphere enterprise applications'
2. Click on 'IBM_Application_Center_Console'
3. Click on 'Security role to user/group mapping'
4. Check both the boxes beside 'appcenteruser' and 'appcenteradmin' and 
   then from the 'Map Special Subjects' choose 'All Authenticated in 
   Application's Realm'
5. Hit ok and save to master configuration.
6. Repeat the above steps for 'IBM_Application_Center_Services'
7. Restart the MobileFirst server and attempt to log in to the Application Center.